# Laravel4 - A calendar inside a form

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, calendar, laravel, laravel-4

I have to make a form where among other fields i have to include a calendar where the user can select the arrival date and the outgoing date.
How can i do that with Laravel4, and retrive the data?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using twitter bootstrap you can make a date picker calendar using this http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Then you can retrieve the selected value using `$date = Input::get('selected_date');` where `selected_date` is your input field name.

Comment: Oh thank you man! I am indeed using Bootstrap so it is exactly what i was looking for! I will ask help if i will have some issues!

Comment: Good, you can ask at any time.

Comment: Not that you aren't allowed to ask here because we love questions, but you would have a much better chance at getting the help you need if you tagged twitter-bootstrap on any future questions having to do with this topic.

Comment: Hi Devo! I have issues indeed! :)
I am not able to setup properly the package.
I write a new question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272070/bootstrap-how-to-add-dropdown-less