# Bootstrap: How to add dropdown.less?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to add a calendar into a form.
I want to install this project:
https://github.com/vitalets/bootstrap-datepicker

But it is said that:
Requires bootstrap’s dropdown component (dropdowns.less) for some styles, and bootstrap’s sprites (sprites.less and associated images) for arrows.

How can i add that files to my app?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to download and include the following assets.

### CSS

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css

http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css

### JS

http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js

http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

Then in html, use like this.

```
<input data-provide="datepicker">
```

### [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/PBcFK/)

Please note that, I have given bootstrap 2.3 here.

Comment: This doesn't include the optional CSS for arrow images, etc.

Comment: Demo given here is not functional. It takes you to a fiddle, but it is broken/not implemented properly.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide the files asked for (sprites and dropdown)