# bootstrap-datepicker is displayed in the bottom of the page

Tags: html, bootstrap-datepicker

I use this example 
[Bootstrap: How to add dropdown.less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272070/bootstrap-how-to-add-dropdown-less)

And in example it works great, but in my project I have input with datepicker in table row, and when I click on it, calendar shows in the bottom of the page.
How I can resolve this problem?

Bootstrap-datepicker fork page:
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Please provide a link to your site or a jsfiddle with your codes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HUSTLIN/wa37owL6/
This is a table like in my project, I can't add project page because it's commercial.

Comment: In the jsfiddle of yours, the calendar shows on top and not below. It's hard for us to debug this without seeing the the codes you used for the datepicker

Comment: I think the calendar popup shows in the end of <body> not near my input.

Comment: I add a little update to my jsfiddle, calendar shows on top not in the bottom as I had described, but it's a problem too, because it's not near input.

Comment: I will need to see more codes to fix the issue for you unfortunately.